# Node.js socket.io peer to peer communication for data sharing

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple peer to peer data sharing platform using node-fetch and socket.io.
Given the sender and receiver's ip, the sender transmits data to the receiver's computer using node-fetch.
The receiver captures the data using socket.io and can reply using the 'req.host' ip.
The code runs fine but the message sent is not received at the /receive endpoint.

What could be the problem?
Is there a better way to do this?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // Data fetch feature
const socket = require('socket.io');
const client = require('socket.io-client');
const express = require('express');
var ip = require("ip");

var senderIP =`${ip.address()}; // Test IP

// Express configurations
const app = express()
const port = 60553 // Processing Port

// Send parameters
var pcURL=`http://${senderIP}:${port}/receive`;

app.get('/send', async (req, res) => {

var msg ='Hello from Vakindu!';

// Send Message
let sendMsg = await fetch(pcURL, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({data: msg})
            }) 
            .then(() =>  {  
                return msg; 
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));  

res.end(sendMsg);

});

// Receive message
app.get('/receive', (req, res) => {

let newMsg='';

// Notification center
client(pcURL).on('', (msg) => {

    newMsg=msg

});

res.end('New Message:'+newMsg);

});

// Port session listener
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`P2P Network started on port ${port} ...!`)
})

// Socket setup
const io = socket(server);
```

Comment: What seems to be error? Does the code run? Or does it perform unexpectedly ? This is also a wrong use of the `then` block. why are you returning msg if you've declared it? Essentially You need to restructure your question to be clearer so we can help.

Comment: The code runs fine but the message sent is not received at the /receive endpoint.
The return in then is to display message sent to sender.